# PHP strange If Else loop output if i make exact opposite of current condition

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

what i am trying to do check the `$_GET['mode']` for specific page types,
if mode is favorites , rss or my_uploads page then dont show the RSS link
like this

```
<?php
$mode = $_GET['mode'];
if($mode == 'favorites' || $mode == 'rss' || $mode == 'my_uploads'){
$RSS_link = null;
}else{
$RSS_link = create rss link logic here ;
}
```

then later showing the link to RSS FEED only if the link is created like this

```
<?=(isset($RSS_link)) ? '<a href="'.$RSS_link.'">RSS FEED</a>' : '' ;?>
```

the above code is working fine, and shows the RSS FEED Link only when pages are not favorites, rss,my_uploads

but if change the RSS creating condition like this.

```
<?php

    if($mode != 'favorites' || $mode != 'rss' || $mode != 'my_uploads'){
    $RSS_link = create rss link logic here ;
    }else{
    $RSS_link = null;
    }
```

i.e. just changing the operators to opposite and moving if to else and else to if,

```
<?=(isset($RSS_link)) ? '<a href="'.$RSS_link.'">RSS FEED</a>' : '' ;?>
```

and then try to show the RSS FEED Link , it shows the link, no matter what the mode is set.

Why is this happening?
How can i fix this ?

Comment: why the negative votes, its pure logic and innocent coding , thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your condition

```
$mode != 'favorites' || $mode != 'rss' || $mode != 'my_uploads'
```

to

```
$mode != 'favorites' && $mode != 'rss' && $mode != 'my_uploads'
```

It's common variant of usage [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

You could always check your logic with tables.

```
$mode = 'favorites';
$mode != 'favorites' || $mode != 'rss' || $mode != 'my_uploads'
//    ^ false                 ^ true            ^ true
//                   ^ true
//                                     ^ true
```

Result true.

```
$mode = 'favorites';
$mode != 'favorites' && $mode != 'rss' && $mode != 'my_uploads'
//    ^ false                 ^ true            ^ true
//                   ^ false
//                                     ^ false
```

Result false.

Comment: but wont that look for all 3 modes at a time ?.,

Comment: @AMB it's the law of De Morgan, i.e you can switch `!(A || B)` to `!A && !B`

Comment: @RaphaelMüller thats the explanation i was lookinh for , the law is too heavy for me for now., thanks

Comment: @AMB Just think about the logic, `not 1 OR not 2` will always be true.

Comment: it's a common pitfall... `a != x || b != y` is NOT the logical reverse of `a == x || b == y`

Comment: i just made my condition like this if($mode != ('favorites'|| 'rss' || 'my_uploads')){ and its working.,

Comment: @AMB check logic tables.

Comment: @AMB watch out, I think you are comparing $mode to true! (`('foo' || 'bar')` is always true)